# Getting grouped data from a table

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a table named `trades`
The trades table has the following schema:

```
id (int)
exchange_name (VARCHAR)
exchange_icon (VARCHAR)
trade_time (bigint)
price_quote (int)
price_usd (int)
trade_value (int)
base_asset_icon (VARCHAR)
qty (int)
quoteQty (int)
is_buyer_maker (boolean)
pair (VARCHAR)
base_asset_trade (VARCHAR)
quote_asset_trade (VARCHAR)
```

I need data in the this format:

```
    base_asset_trade
    base_asset_icon
    sold: (number of times is_buyer_maker was **true** for this base asset)
    bought: (number of times is_buyer_maker was **false** for this base asset)
    sold_trade_value: (sum of trade_value for all where base asset is sold)
    bought_trade_value: (sum of trade_value for all where base asset is bought)
    price_usd
total_trades: (sum of bought and sold)
```

How can I get these results using postgres queries?

So far I have tried this:

```
SELECT base_asset_trade, trade_value, price_in_usd, base_asset_icon, is_buyer_maker  
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM trades 
      WHERE  trade_time / 1000 > (extract(epoch from now()) - (86400)*1))
) AS derivedTable 
GROUP BY is_buyer_maker
```

But this is giving several errors.

Sample output:

```
base_asset: BTC
base_asset_icon: btc.png
sold: 48
bought: 56
sold_trade_value: 200000000
bought_trade_value: 25644300
price: 19000
total_trades: 104
```

Comment: Can you share sample input and expected output, and your best coding attempt at this problem?

Comment: Sure, let me edit

Comment: Please check the edits

Comment: What do you expect/desire to be in the `price_usd` column? The average, the min or max, for all trades or just sold or just bought, etc...

Comment: For your sample, please include sample input data as well. By including both input and output we can then see what you're describing, and use that data to test and demonstrate any answer.

Comment: For price, just the price value for that base asset

Comment: Also what do you mean by "something being **true**"? You can have a string 'true', or you can have the value 1, or either the value 0, or whatever value you want to mean it being true, it can dramatically vary according to the nature of your input data.

Comment: Let me add more information

Comment: The is_buyer_maker column is boolean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear what constitues true or false, so the case expressions you see here may need correction, but the structure of the query should apply. You need a `group by` clause and aggregation functions count and sum.

```
SELECT
      base_asset_trade
    , base_asset_icon
    , count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'sold' THEN 1 END) AS sold
    , count(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'bought' THEN 1 END) AS bought
    , sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'sold' THEN trade_value ELSE 0 END) AS sold_trade_value
    , sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker = 'bought' THEN trade_value ELSE 0 END) AS bought_trade_value
    , price_usd
    , sum(trade_value) AS total_trades
FROM trades
GROUP BY
      base_asset_trade
    , base_asset_icon
    , price_usd
```

Note: when using case expressions inside an aggregation function it is known as "conditional aggregation".

Comment: You can remove `ELSE 0`  from your `CASE` statements.

Comment: Depends on your approach to warnings, sql server for exame issues a warning if a sum encounters null values, so i prefer to include the else zero. Btw. They are **case expressions**

Comment: This is giving different rows for the same base asset. Is there a way that we can group it so it shows all data for one base asset in the same row?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell also total_trades should be the sum of number of bought and sold, but it is giving a huge value

Comment: If ("huge value" > ("sold" + "bought") ) then try `sum(CASE WHEN is_buyer_maker IN ('bought','sold') THEN trade_value ELSE 0 END) AS total_trades` but you need to understand you have provided no sample data - and that severly limits what we can do to help you. (My guessing ability has limits)